# What are the ways to extract numbers from string and add some text in the middle with lambda java lists

Tags: java, list, lambda, java-stream, predicate

So I have a task to modify list of strings (or more extract from it) parts and then add some text to it in the beginning, middle and also convert numbers to integer and then multiply it by given rate. In one part of the task i need to use lambda and my own class in the next i have to use streams to extract and modify all of this.
I seek more like clues than a code. What methods to use and some instructuions on how to do that. More of the requirements are in the code in comments
I would be really thankful.

```
import java.util.*;

public class ListCreator<S,T> {

List<T> list;

protected ListCreator(List<T> listcreate){
    this.list = listcreate; //kreator robi nowa liste zeby nie modyfikowac
}

public static <S,T> ListCreator<S,T> collectFrom(List<T> srclist){
    ListCreator<S,T> listCreator = new ListCreator<S,T>(srclist);
    listCreator.list = srclist; //tworzy liste lc z zawartoscia listy ktora chce zbadac/zmodyfikowac
    return listCreator;
}

public ListCreator<S,T> when(Selector<T> selector){
    List<T> nextlist = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
        T arg = list.get(i); //biore indeksy kazdego z elementow
        if(selector.select(arg)){ //patrze czy spelniaja warunki
           nextlist.add(arg);

        }
    }
    this.list = nextlist; /// w koncu przepisuje nextlist do tego obiektu uffff zmarnowalam na tym najwiecej czasu
    return this;
}

public <S> List<S> mapEvery(Mapper<T,S> mapper){
    List<S> dlist = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
        T arg = list.get(i); //zbieram indeksy elementow jako typu T
        S modarg = mapper.map(arg); //kazdy argument modyfikuje i przypisuje jako argument danego typu
        dlist.add(modarg); // dodaje zmodyfikowany element
    }
    return dlist;
}
}  

import java.util.*;

public class Main {

static List<String> getPricesInPLN(List<String> destinations, double xrate) {
return ListCreator.collectFrom(destinations)
                   .when(e -> e.startsWith("WAW") /*<-- lambda wyrażenie
                            *  selekcja wylotów z Warszawy (zaczynających się od WAW)
                            */
                    )
                   .mapEvery(f -> f.
                           ); /*<-- lambda that creates (multiplies by) the price using the following rate of ratePLNvsEUR and then maps all of it to the result text on console
                               */

   }

  /* main class for first task using lambdas and listcreator to extract 
 all the factors into following result on the console:
 to HAV - price in PLN: 5160
 to DPS - price in PLN: 8600
 to HKT - price in PLN: 4300
   */
rate
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // these are the destination airports 
List<String> dest = Arrays.asList(
  "bleble bleble 2000",
  "WAW HAV 1200",
  "xxx yyy 789",
  "WAW DPS 2000",
  "WAW HKT 1000"
);
double ratePLNvsEUR = 4.30;
List<String> result = getPricesInPLN(dest, ratePLNvsEUR);
for (String r : result) System.out.println(r);
 }
 }

 // main to second task where I need to do all of the previous one but in 
 // one stream without using the listcreator class

  /*<-- imports */

 public class Main {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
// Lista destynacji: port_wylotu port_przylotu cena_EUR 
List<String> dest = Arrays.asList(
  "bleble bleble 2000",
  "WAW HAV 1200",
  "xxx yyy 789",
  "WAW DPS 2000",
  "WAW HKT 1000"
);
double ratePLNvsEUR = 4.30;
List<String> result = 
/*<-- here should be a stream

for (String r : result) System.out.println(r);
}
}
```

Comment: Many of your comments are in Polish (according to google translate) so it's difficult to read.

Comment: The polish ones aren’t important it’s just me explaining to myself what am I doing there xd sorry for the unclarity

Comment: Don't forget about `Integer.parseInt()` or `Integer.valueOf()`

Comment: Okay but what about dividing into parts so I can modify strings?

Comment: `String[] s = String.split(" ");` which splits the given String and splits it by spaces. Also, you may need to check if it is valid to call parseInt/valueOf with these Strings with something like `String.charAt(index)` (called multiple times for each word) otherwise, you may get a `java.lang.NumberFormatException`.